# Little problem with carp_background_location flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm having a little problem. I'm using carp_background_location and is work almost perfectly, but, I need to stop the location service when app is closed. I have this part of the code, which observe the lifecycle:

```
`@override
  Future<void> didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) async {
    super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
   if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
  inactivityTimer?.cancel();
  isInInactiveState = false;
  var newStatus = await ph.Permission.location.request();
  if (newStatus.isGranted) {
    start();
  }
}
print(state);
if(state == AppLifecycleState.detached){ not work here
  locationSubscription?.cancel();
  LocationManager().stop();
}else if(state == AppLifecycleState.inactive){works here
  print("inactive");
  locationSubscription?.cancel();
  LocationManager().stop();
}`
```

When I close the app, the "closed" print comes, but the logs continue to come for some reason, and when I put the second if "inactive" the print doesn't come, but the logs stop as expected, but the problem is: when I put it inactive , location also doesn't work in the background, and I need it. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you have stopped the location while the app is in INACTIVE mode!

Remove or comment the `LocationManager().Stop()` and it should work.

```
else if (state == AppLifecycleState.inactive) { // works here  
  print("inactive");
  locationSubscription?.cancel();  
  LocationManager().stop();
}
```

Comment: As I said, if I remove that part, my location service continues. The location doesn't stop on detached for some reason just on inactive or paused...